# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout(Lollipop without Activity)

Tags: android

I have a view added with WindowManager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/MyTabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here's my java code:

```
Context context = My ApplicationContext;
context.setTheme(R.style.MyStyle);
// context.setTheme(R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents); not working
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
mRootView = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null); //Crash!

...

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    mRootParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
} else {
    mRootParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
}
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
}
```

My `MyTabLayoutStyle` is inherit from `Widget.Design.TabLayout` and `MyStyle` is inherit from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. Use `context.setTheme(R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents)` instead of `context.setTheme(R.style.MyStyle)` is still not working.

**These code works on android 9/10, but not work on android 5(Lollipop).**

I read [Getting started with Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) and it doesn't say how to use TabLayout without Activity. And I can't new instance AppCompatDelegate without Activity.
How can I make it work on android 5? Help!

Crash Log:

```
E/ActivityThread( 6726): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at myview.initViews
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at ...
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1255)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1138)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:136)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1989)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6138)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:160)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1125)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:809)
E/ActivityThread( 6726): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
E/ActivityThread( 6726):        ... 45 more
```

Comment: if you remove TabLayout from the layout, does it work fine?

Answer (score 0):

The `TabLayout` in the Material Components Library requires a [Material Components Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) or a [Bridge Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes-bridge-themes).

Also you are using the `ApplicationContext`. The `ApplicationContext` **hasn't** the app theme.
Use `getActivity` as `Context`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I try `context.setTheme(R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents);`, it still not working. And there's no activity is running when I show my view. So I can't call use `getActivity`

Comment: @android_su It is only a theme overlay. You need to use a Material Components theme as app theme. Post the full stacktrace and the code when you use the TabLayout.